# JQuery Json error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, wcf, json

**ERROR: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**

here is how the json2 is calling from:

```
   **var json = JSON2.stringify(settings.data);**
```

i am using WCF service to pull the data and its very simple for the purpose of test and it does returning me the data from wcf service but it fails on json2.js on **line number 314-316**

```
// We split the first stage into 4 regexp operations in order to work around
// crippling inefficiencies in IE's and Safari's regexp engines. First we
// replace all backslash pairs with '@' (a non-JSON character). Second, we
// replace all simple value tokens with ']' characters. Third, we delete all
// open brackets that follow a colon or comma or that begin the text. Finally,
// we look to see that the remaining characters are only whitespace or ']' or
// ',' or ':' or '{' or '}'. If that is so, then the text is safe for eval.

                if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {
```

here is what i am doing

```
    // *** Generic Service Proxy class that can be used to 
// *** call JSON Services generically using jQuery
// *** Depends on JSON2 modified for MS Ajax usage
function serviceProxy(wjOrderServiceURL) {
    var _I = this;
    this.ServiceURL = wjOrderServiceURL;

    // *** Call a wrapped object
    this.invoke = function (options) {

        // Default settings
        var settings = {
            serviceMethod: '',
            data: null,
            callback: null,
            error: null,
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json", 
            dataType: "text",
            bare: false
        };

        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        // *** Convert input data into JSON - REQUIRES Json2.js
        var json = JSON2.stringify(settings.data);

        // *** The service endpoint URL
        var url = _I.ServiceURL + settings.serviceMethod;
      debugger
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: json,
            type: settings.type,
            processData: settings.processData,
            contentType: settings.contentType,
            timeout: settings.timeout,
            error: settings.error,
            dataType: settings.dataType,
            success:
                    function (res) {
                        if (!settings.callback) { return; }

                        // *** Use json library so we can fix up MS AJAX dates
                        var result = JSON2.parse(res);
                        debugger
                        if (result.ExceptionDetail) {
                            OnPageError(result.Message);
                            return;
                        }

                        // *** Bare message IS result
                        if (settings.bare)
                        { settings.callback(result); return; }

                        //http://encosia.com/2009/07/21/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/
                        if (result.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                        { return settings.callback(result.d); }
                        else
                        { return result; }


                        // *** Wrapped message contains top level object node
                        // *** strip it off
                        //                        for (var property in result) {
                        //                            settings.callback(result[property]);
                        //                            break;
                        //                        }
                    }
        });
    };
}



 function GetFederalHolidays() {

        $("#dContacts1").empty().html('Searching for Active Contacts...');  
        ContactServiceProxy.invoke({ serviceMethod: "Holidays",
            callback: function (response) {
    //           ProcessActiveContacts1(response);
                debugger
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorMsg, thrown) {
                postErrorAndUnBlockUI(xhr, errorMsg, thrown);
            }
        });        
}
```

wcf is returning me simple string

```
  public List<string> Holidays()
        {
            List<string> s = new List<string>();
            s.Add("01/01/2010");
            s.Add("02/01/2010");
            s.Add("03/01/2010");
            s.Add("04/01/2010");
            s.Add("05/01/2010");
            return s;

        }
```

any help what iam doing wrong? i try to change from dataType: text to json but i get the same error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out, the problem was that it was expecting an object (Holiday)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.invoke = function (options) {
```

First thing is to close that function with a matching `};`.

And another `}` to close the first function, `serviceProxy`.

Comment: ok, i just update the whole code, previously i just copy part of code thats why you found the missing closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the error is in `Json2.js`. I personally get very skeptical when I see custom JSON libraries in JS. I would advise trying something like this:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/

I've used it numerous times in the past and it's been simply wonderful.

It should also be mentioned that the standard way of accessing JSON functions in a standards-compliant browser is via something like `JSON.stringify(...)` and not through `JSON2`. If you are using a modern browser, you shouldn't need to use a separate library to do JSON.

Best regards